# Deleting OLEObjects checkboxes from VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

this works perfectly

```
For Each oleObject In wks.OLEObjects
    If TypeName(oleObject.Object) = "OptionButton" Then oleObj.Delete
Next
```

but when trying to delete checkboxes is not working. Nothing happens

```
For Each oleObject In wks.OLEObjects
    If TypeName(oleObject.Object) = "Checkbox" Then oleObj.Delete
Next
```

Comment: `If TypeName(oleObject.Object) = "CheckBox" Then oleObject.Delete`. Using `Debug.Print TypeName(oleObject.Object)` would have helped spot the issue.

Comment: ... not to mention `Option Explicit`.

Answer (score 1):

Use progId.

```
Sub test()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim obj As OLEObject
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    
    For Each obj In wks.OLEObjects
        Debug.Print TypeName(obj)
        Debug.Print obj.progID
        If obj.progID = "Forms.CheckBox.1" Then obj.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```